# ng-animate not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate, ng-show

I am trying to do a simple fade in of an element when a boolean variable is set to true. It was working fine earlier, until I changed my `AngularJS` version to `1.2.15`. Am I doing something incorrectly?

[Here is a sample JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/QErPe/117/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    {{ready}}
    <div ng-show="ready" ng-animate="{show:'animate-show'}">hello</div>
</div>

$scope.ready = false;

function displayBox() {
    $scope.ready = true;
    $scope.$apply();
}
setTimeout(displayBox, 1000);
```

Comment: Did you include `angular-animate`

Comment: Are you supposed to? That is probably it.

Comment: Yeah, there's a separate script for it. Add that, make a dependency reference and you should be good

Comment: Hmm. Still doesn't work, unless I added the dependency incorrectly. http://jsfiddle.net/QErPe/117/

Comment: checkout this article on [animation](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation syntax changed in Angular 1.2.x. Now you have to use `ngAnimate` module as dependency and change the way you apply animation with CSS. Your HTML becomes:

```
<div class="animate-show" ng-show="ready">hello</div>
```

And in your situation you only need this simple CSS:

```
.animate-show {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
}
.animate-show.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/nHZ6P6evV2Ee4NtIeMZY?p=preview

Comment: Excellent research! I knew it was something along these lines, I just couldn't find any documentation. You're the best!

Comment: Here is `ngShow` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow), it have information about animation too.